# Disk boot failure from time to time that dissolves upon another reboot

Tags: windows, hard-drive, boot, windows-8.1, mbr

I'm running a Windows 8.1 on my PC, all of a sudden this PC started rebooting (while idling) and printing out the DISK BOOT FAILURE disgusting error. When I reboot the computer once again everything works flawlessly. It happened to me once before but I've ignored it. I told myself that if it would happen again I will diagnose it - now it happened again, what am I supposed to do? Am I losing my hard drive?

**Edit:** Attaching HD Tune Health:

```
HD Tune: SAMSUNG HD103SJ Health

ID                               Current  Worst    ThresholdData     Status   
(01) Raw Read Error Rate         100      100      51       544      Ok       
(02) Throughput Performance      252      252      0        0        Ok       
(03) Spin Up Time                71       68       25       8914     Ok       
(04) Start/Stop Count            100      100      0        461      Ok       
(05) Reallocated Sector Count    252      252      10       0        Ok       
(07) Seek Error Rate             252      252      51       0        Ok       
(08) Seek Time Performance       252      252      15       0        Ok       
(09) Power On Hours Count        100      100      0        23714    Ok       
(0A) Spin Retry Count            252      252      51       0        Ok       
(0B) Calibration Retry Count     252      252      0        0        Ok       
(0C) Power Cycle Count           100      100      0        459      Ok       
(BF) G-sense Error Rate          252      252      0        0        Ok       
(C0) Power Off Retract Count     252      252      0        0        Ok       
(C2) Temperature                 64       60       0        1114140  Ok       
(C3) Hardware ECC Recovered      100      100      0        0        Ok       
(C4) Reallocated Event Count     252      252      0        0        Ok       
(C5) Current Pending Sector      100      100      0        15       Ok       
(C6) Offline Uncorrectable       252      252      0        0        Ok       
(C7) Ultra DMA CRC Error Count   200      200      0        0        Ok       
(C8) Write Error Rate            100      100      0        233      Ok       
(DF) Load/Unload Retry Count     252      252      0        0        Ok       
(E1) Load/Unload Cycle Count     100      100      0        465      Ok       

Power On Time         : 23714
Health Status         : Ok
```

Comment: Try Hardware trouble shooting. Remove the HardDive and attach again. Disk Cable maybe dusty!

Comment: Use [HD Tune](http://www.hdtune.com/download.html) to retrieve SMART data from your hard drive (it's the *Health* tab in HD Tune). Include the data in your question. You can mention me in a comment in case nobody takes some time to analyze it.

Comment: @gronostaj, I have added the required information.

Comment: I'm guessing that the problem is not with the drive, but with the motherboard or memory.  Or perhaps a "brown out" with a weak power supply.  If this only happened when the system was in heavy use I'd suspect overheating.

Comment: @DanielRHicks, Please see my comments to the answer below.

Comment: My guess stands.  The problem is probably not with the drives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your hard disk's SMART data (self-diagnostics) don't show any signs of failure. The lack of bluescreens when PC restarts makes pinpointing the issue harder, though.

Spontaneous restarts can be caused by a number of problems. I'd start with testing RAM for any possible problems (with memtest86+ or similar software). Another point of failure may be the PSU, which can sometimes underpower some component, causing instant reboot and the hard disk problem that follows it. It can also be caused by failing motherboard (look for leaking capacitors) or some other issues that are hard to guess until the problem gets worse.

Comment: I found it hard to believe that the PSU is failing since it's a Seasonic 550W, so I have opened up my computer's case (a great opportunity to clean out some dust) and looked out for leaking capacitors but found nothing. So now I'm going to run memtest and I'll get back to you with the results.

Comment: Crap, as I'm searching for a memtest86+ for x64 I get this Windows error message: http://i.imgur.com/UpRDyvW.png What am I to do now? Might this be causing the troubles?

Comment: You probably have a hard disk problem not related to its physical condition, but rather caused by filesystem corruption caused by those restarts. Stop using your PC until you have some external disk to backup your data to (or if you're familiar with Linux then boot some LiveCD distro, mount your partitions read-only and backup from there, generally speaking limit disk usage to minimum). You can attempt to fix the problem, but if it won't work it'll make it worse, so backup is the first thing to do right now.

Comment: How would you suggest fixing the filesystem corruption?

Comment: I have disconnected the harddrive mounted as D:\ for now. How can I check for filesystem errors on the one mounted as C:\?

Comment: You can open Start screen, type `cmd`, right click the visible item and choose Run as Administrator. Confirm the UAC prompt and you should see a command line. Type `chkdsk c:` and press Enter to perform read-only disk scan. But again, you should first concentrate on backing up all important data in case the situation gets worse. When you're done with backup you can try `chkdsk /r c:` to attempt repair of damaged sectors, but you may end up loosing some files.

Comment: Alright so I've chkdsk'ed C: and these are the results: http://i.imgur.com/qmSSuUK.png Which gets me to the conclusion that only the harddrive of D: is corrupted in some way.

Comment: That's possible. Can you post SMART readings from your second HDD? You can switch disks in HD Tune's window.

Comment: Sure, http://pastebin.com/D0reNc5W

Comment: This one looks fine too. Now you should make sure your data is safe, then you can try to solve the original problem.

Comment: Data is safe, how shall I proceed?

Comment: Now you can try to fix the filesystem with `chkdsk /r d:`. If it fails, format the disk and restore your data from backup. If it succeeds, your disk is fixed for now. Diagnosing the cause of sudden restarts will be a bit harder. How old is the computer? Have you replaced some parts since you've bought it?

Comment: It happened again over the last night :( I don't know what to do anymore/

Comment: @Eran Is the machine old? Did it have some parts replaced?

Comment: The machine is not old, it is 3 years old and I had no parts replaced lately. It happened just as mentioned in OP, during night, I unplugged and replugged the power cable and everything went back to work. I'm creeped out.

Comment: Try disconnecting and reconnecting all PSU plugs one by one, it may be some loose plug. You can also consider borrowing another PSU for replacement. And check your HDD with `chkdsk /r` once again.

Comment: Snap, while I chkdsk /r 'Scanning and repairing drive (C:)' froze on 12%. :(

Comment: Be patient, freezing usually isn't abnormal during this process. It can freeze or proceed very slowly at some point even on a healthy drive. Nothing to worry about yet.

Comment: Ah, i left it to run during night and when I came back in the morning the same damn boot error screen waited for me.

Comment: It just freezes on 12%

Comment: If you still have backups you've made before then reinstalling Windows with full format may be the best solution. But first test your RAM with memtest and check PSU plugs, maybe switch to another PSU for a month and see if the problem persists. 3 year old machine can have MoBo capacitor problems, so ruling out PSU would make diagnosing the problem easier.

Comment: How can I know if it's the mobo? I don't have a spare one to replace and wait for errors :/

Comment: Hopefully the problem will disappear with a new PSU, so you'll know it was the culprit. Make sure the one you'll use for replacement can provide enough power. If it's not the PSU nor RAM, then it's very likely the MoBo, but you can't be sure unless you replace it *and* the PSU. Low-quality PSUs that provide unstable voltage are the main reason of MoBo failures.

Comment: But my PSU isn't cheap. Is there a way to test the PSU before purchasing a new one?

Comment: Will splitting my drive into 2 partitions and backing up to one of them while formatting the other that had Windows on it might do the trick or do I have to fully format the whole drive?

Comment: I'm not aware of any reliable ways of checking a PSU. For now you just want to have that corrupted partition reformatted, splitting it may corrupt data even further. And you should have external backup anyway, no matter if your drive is malfunctioning or not.